# How can I get jQuery-ui menu element id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have simple menu

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="test_li_id">
    <div id="test_div_id">Just one element</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<script>
$('#menu').menu();
$('#menu').on("menufocus", function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui.id);
    console.log(ui[0].id);
    console.log($(ui).attr("id"));
    })
</script
```

All of this don't give me id, I've tried some more variants without success. How can I get `id` of element. I suppose `ui` inside function neither jQuery object nor DOM object. From `google chrome dev tools` I can't figure how to get it. It just says that `id` doesn't exist, but I see it in object. And path looks like `S.fn.init>item>0>id`

`$(this)` gives me root element, and not suitable if i have submenus.

P.S. Yes, I need "menufocus" and not "menuselect".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `ui.item[0].id` like:

```js
$('#menu').menu();
$('#menu').on("menufocus", function(event, ui) {
  console.log(ui.item[0].id);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-hlKLmzaRlE8SCJC1Kw8zoUbU8BxA+8kR3gseuKfMjxA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul id="menu">
  <li id="test_li_id">
    <div id="test_div_id">Just one element</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Next time for check use `console.log(ui)` you will see all list of node

Comment: Yes. It works. I looked at nodes. But can't setup path for unknown reason ( I didn't try "item" i thought that that's some inner object field and can't be addressed

Comment: Perfect, the important thing that it works :)